# How to prevent screen sleep in react native

Tags: react-native, screen, video-processing

I want to awake screen while playing video
NativeModules.KCKeepAwake.activate() is depreciated in react native

Any other solution?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using expo you can use: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/keep-awake/

If you are not using expo then you can use: https://github.com/marcshilling/react-native-idle-timer#readme